# Что делает конструкция к квадратных скобках?

Tags: javascript, циклы, числа-фибоначчи, yield, рекуррентность

Код возвращает последовательно каждое число Фибоначчи
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55...

```
// @return {Iterable.<number>}

function* getFibonacciSequence() {
    let a = 0, b = 1;
    while (true) {
        yield a;
        b = [a + b, a = b][0];
    }
}
```

Непонятно, что делает строчка **b = [a + b, a = b][0];**

Это синтаксический сахар какой-то? К чему здесь квадратные скобки, этот 0 и вообще что за синтаксис? Если можно, то напишите эту же строчку другим (более простым) способом.

Answer (score 0):

> Непонятно, что делает строчка b = [a + b, a = b][0];

Это просто укороченная версия вот такой вещи

```
let temp = b
b = a + b;
a = temp;
```

Работает это, потому что перед тем, как вернуть значение в `b`, нам нужно создать массив, элемент в массиве можно определить через выражение, тогда значение элемента будет равно значению, которое вернет выражение, например:

```
const a = [1 + 1, console.log('invoked')][0]; // a = 2
```

`console.log` выведет `invoke`

Comment: @AlexeyTen так в этом и смысл, весь код это генератор чисел фибоначи, поэтому в `a` сохраняется предыдущее число, а в `b` текущее

Answer (score 0):

В квадратных скобках просто создаётся временный массив и из него берётся первый элемент.

```
let tmp = b;
b = a + b;
a = tmp;
```

Просто кому-то очень не хотелось вводить временную переменную (поэтому он создал временный массив, что потребовало, наверное, раз в 10 больше ресурсов, зато красиво).

UPD: можно и без временной переменной:

```
// пусть b=8, a=5
b = b + a; // теперь b=13, a=5
a = b - a; // b=13, a=13-5=8, что и требовалось
```

но читать такой код и понимать что происходит уже сложнее